# Not saving data to realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i tried debugging but can't find anything in logcat im using
`if (pickupLatLng != null && destinationLatLng != null){}` to store pickupLatLng and destinationLatLng.

```
    if (pickupLatLng != null && destinationLatLng != null) {
         HashMap map = new HashMap();
         map.put("driver", userId);
         map.put("customer", customerId);
         map.put("rating", 0);
         map.put("timestamp", getCurrentTimestamp());
         map.put("destination", destination);
         map.put("location/from/lat", pickupLatLng.latitude);
         map.put("location/from/lng", pickupLatLng.longitude);
         map.put("location/to/lat", 
         destinationLatLng.latitude);
         map.put("location/to/lng", 
         destinationLatLng.longitude);
         map.put("distance", rideDistance);
         historyRef.child(requestId).updateChildren(map);
     }
```

Below code works just fine if i don't use `if (pickupLatLng != null && destinationLatLng != null){}`

```
HashMap map = new HashMap();
     map.put("driver", userId);
     map.put("customer", customerId);
     map.put("rating", 0);
     map.put("timestamp", getCurrentTimestamp());
     map.put("destination", destination);
```

i also tried completion handler but no luck
here is the code im trying to follow https://github.com/SimCoderYoutube/UberClone/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/simcoder/uber/DriverMapActivity.java

Comment: 1) Are there any relevant messages written to the logcat when you call `updateChildren`? 2) Can you [add a completion handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback) and see if the operation completes successfully? 3) If neither of those works, can you [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and see what is written to the logcat around the call to `updateChildren`?

Comment: i don't see anything in logcat, im using if (pickupLatLng != null && destinationLatLng != null) {} only for this 4 lines
map.put("location/from/lat", pickupLatLng.latitude);
     map.put("location/from/lng", pickupLatLng.longitude);
     map.put("location/to/lat", destinationLatLng.latitude);
     map.put("location/to/lng", destinationLatLng.longitude);
This works just fine
HashMap map = new HashMap();
   map.put("driver", userId);
   map.put("customer", customerId);
   map.put("rating", 0);
   map.put("timestamp", getCurrentTimestamp());
   map.put("destination", destination);

Comment: Oof, that is pretty unreadable in a comment. Instead please edit your question (there's a link right under it) to address all 3 questions that I asked. Including such basic debugging information drastically increases the chances that someone can help.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank van Puffelen asked for, and please also responded with @.